# Clonezilla image restore to Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, backup, clonezilla

Maybe this is not the right place to ask, but i dont get any reply on sourceforge...

Just recently i made an image backup from a 320GB harddisk where in only 15GB is in use. So the next  thing i did is creating a virtual machine of 60GB to restore the image in. Then it gave me the error destination disk to small. while i only want to restore the 15GB in use to 60GB VBOX harddisk not the whole 320 GB. So my question is, is there a possibility to make the this work ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make the virtual disk in the vm dynamically allocated when you create it, then you can make it as big as you want (500G or whatever), and it will only take up physical disk space for what is actually used + some overhead.

Then you can resize it in the VM later if you want.

I've actually done this in order to downsize a Clonezilla image - I took a 2nd clone of the smaller VM disk.